# How to store views related to package

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a package which I use to create some tables based on data in other tables. At the end of that package, I query the information I need via views I have already created. However, I have a bunch of views and I would like to keep them in order somewhere in that package or that has relation to that package. What would be the way to achieve this?

Comment: Views and tables are schema objects. They usually get created once and live forever. If you use them in your package, you may find these relationships via `dba_dependencies` system view. But if you want to bundle them with the package, it would be better to do this in external tool (where you run `create package` from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views and packages are atomic Oracle objects and cannot be created inside each
other.

However Oracle offers another select only PL/SQL "view like" structure - the pipelined function. This may prove useful if grouping of "views" is important in your use case.

You can create many pipelined functions within a single package, each function conceptually creating a different "view". A pipelined function can be referenced in a normal select statement by wrapping it in a table() statement as shown in the example below.

To illustrate I have created a very simple package called "views" which contains a single pipelined function "customers" which returns the customer ids and customer names from the customer table. I could of course include other pipelined functions in my grouping "views" package eg. "invoices", "sales" etc etc. (these functions can also take parameters like any normal package function if desired)

Here follows the simple illustration:

A. create your package specification for your pipelined table "customer view"

```
create or replace package views as

type t_cust_rec is record(id            customer.id%type
                         ,name          customer.name%type
                         );                   
type t_cust_cur is ref cursor return t_cust_rec;
type t_cust_tab is table of t_cust_rec;

function customers
         return t_cust_tab pipelined;

function sales ....;

function invoices ...;

end views;
```

B. create your package body for your pipelined table "customer view"

```
create or replace package body views as

function customers
         return t_cust_tab pipelined
         is 
  sRows t_cust_cur;
  rRow  t_cust_tab;
begin
  open sRows for
    select id
          ,name
    from customer;
  loop
    fetch sRows into rRow;
    exit when sRows%notfound;
    pipe row (rRow);
  end loop;
end;

function sales ....

function invoices ...

end views;
```

C. use your pipelined table function in a normal select statement

```
select *
from table(views.customers)
where name like 'Bob%';

select *
from table(views.sales)
where amount > 10000.00;

select sum(total)
from table(views.invoices);
```

Comment: Notice: since Oracle 12.2 (if I remember correctly) `table` is optional, and in prior releases you had to declare schema type (not package local type) to use pipelined function in pure SQL context. And since 18c there are SQL macros and Polymorphic Table Functions which has very low development overhead (as manually retyping all the columns of a view in `record` type)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them "somewhere in the package", then it would be a **comment** you'd write on your own and take care about maintaining it.

Another - let's call it "dynamic" option - is to query `user_dependencies` any time you want. Here's an example:

This is a view:

```
SQL> create view v_emps as
  2    select d.dname, e.ename, e.job
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.
```

Package that does *something* with the view:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test
  2  as
  3    procedure p_test;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test
  2  as
  3    procedure p_test is
  4      l_cnt number;
  5    begin
  6      select count(*)
  7        into l_cnt
  8        from v_emps;
  9    end;
 10  end;
 11  /

Package body created.
```

Query `user_dependencies`:

```
SQL> select name, referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_dependencies
  3  where name = 'PKG_TEST'
  4    and referenced_owner = 'SCOTT';

NAME                           REFERENCED_NAME      REFERENCED_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------- ------------------
PKG_TEST                       PKG_TEST             PACKAGE
PKG_TEST                       V_EMPS               VIEW

SQL>
```

If you want to restrict it to views only, add yet another condition (that would be line #5 in query):

```
and referenced_type = 'VIEW'
```